# Is calendar input component removed from semantic-ui?

Tags: datetimepicker, semantic-ui

I was looking for a datepicker in Semantic UI, it seems that there were a calendar function for input in version 2.1.4:

```
$('#datepicker').calendar({ type: 'date' });
```

But it was removed in version 2.3.3 !

Why was it removed? Were there any bugs?
Is there any alternative introduced in the new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a calendar component in older versions but it was removed due to lack of documentation and maintenance.

I've been using a plugin [Semantic-UI-Calendar](https://github.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI-Calendar) forked by **mdehoog** from a pull request in Semantic UI repo. It works perfectly with Semantic UI 2.1 up to 2.2.14, the documentation and examples are enough to make it work on your project.  Altough I haven't tested it with Semantic UI version 2.3.3 it should work.